# JSon select node based on condition applied on other node?

Tags: java, json, solr, jackson

I have this Json :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "fl":"solr_url, solr_date",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"solr_body:party",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":19,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-06-19T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/urbanissues"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-27T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/outsideedge"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-27T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/outsideedge/entry/in-defense-of-advani"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-25T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/serendipity"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-26T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/Ragtime"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-24T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/SilkStalkings"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-28T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/RaisinaWatch"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-25T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.economictimes.indiatimes.com/Cursor/entry/the-unbearable-lightness-of-advani-s-rebellion"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-30T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.reuters.com/great-debate/2013/06/17/the-real-irs-scandal/"]},
      {
        "solr_date":"2013-07-29T13:48:02Z",
        "solr_url":["http://blogs.reuters.com/johncabell"]}]
  }}
```

I am using Jackson for parsing. now the problem is I want to select solr_url based on solr_date. This sounds simplistic in DOM parsing, but finding it real difficult to do in Json. Suppose if date is greater than 18 July (I have already done date logic)  select solr_url. Can you please help me on this.

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new URL("json output url"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way maybe:

```
var docs=json.response.docs;
var max=json.response.numFound;
var urls=[];

for(var i=0;i<max;i++){
    if(myDateLogicFunc(docs[i].solr_date))
            urls[]=docs[i].solr_url[0];
}
```

Your urls wich match your date logic are now stored in the urls array.

It's not really more difficult than dom parsing, the "difficulty" is to deal with arrays or objects.

Comment: what is json.response.docs here ? I could not find anything like that in Json ? pasting my java code as well. Do I have to findValues(response) ?

Comment: json is your json; response.docs is the way you acces to the member of your json object.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see it was in java, this solution is for js :)

Comment: but you showed me way. I think I should store date and url in a tuple in Java and then select one based on other, provided number of solr_date and solr_url is same, which is same indeed. Thanks

Comment: Yes the way is ok, but the language is not ;)